# Getting all available folder metadata on OS X using swift

Tags: swift, macos, filesystems, metadata, spotlight

I'm writing a swift program, and I want to list all metadata of a given folder using swift. As I understand, I'll need `NSMetadataItem`. The [reference doc of NSMetadataItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMetadataItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMetadataItem/attributes) is not very clear to me though, so I'm unable to write a code sample here. How to list all metadata of a folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a new instance of NSMetadataItem with the folder's NSURL:

```
let item = NSMetadataItem(URL: folderURL)
```

Then safely unwrap the values:

```
if let item = item,
        attributes = item.valuesForAttributes(item.attributes) {
    print(attributes)
}
```

Here `attributes` is a `[String : AnyObject]` dictionary of the folder metadata attributes, like:

> ["_kTimeMachineIsCreationMarker": 1, "kMDItemFSCreationDate": 2015-03-09 11:49:57 +0000, "_kTimeMachineOldestSnapshot": 2016-01-29 14:50:21 +0000, "kMDItemFSNodeCount": 4, "kMDItemFSTypeCode": 0, "kMDItemFSLabel": 0, "kMDItemFSContentChangeDate": 2015-05-05 15:24:42 +0000, "kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID": 20, "kMDItemFSFinderFlags": 0, "kMDItemFSName": Shared Playground Data, "kMDItemContentCreationDate": 2015-03-09 11:49:57 +0000, "kMDItemKind": Dossier, "kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden": 0, "_kTimeMachineNewestSnapshot": 4001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000, "kMDItemFSOwnerUserID": 501, "kMDItemFSInvisible": 0, "kMDItemContentTypeTree": <__NSArrayI 0x7f9fdbc05b70>(
>   public.folder,
>   public.directory,
>   public.item
>   )
>   , "kMDItemContentModificationDate": 2015-05-05 15:24:42 +0000, "kMDItemContentType": public.folder, "kMDItemDateAdded": 2015-03-09 11:49:57 +0000, "kMDItemDisplayName": Shared Playground Data, "kMDItemFSCreatorCode": 0]

Comment: I 've try this script in swift 4 and I always get an error on item (found nil). Could you give more details on how should the url be declared?

Comment: @Fredo Does your app have proper sandbox disk entitlements? Check that, and try with Leo's example. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend NSURL to get all metadata from your url as follow:

```
extension NSURL {
    var metadataItemAttributes: [String]? {
        return  NSMetadataItem(URL: self)?.attributes
    }
    var creationDateValue: NSDate? {
        return  NSMetadataItem(URL: self)?.valueForAttribute(NSMetadataItemFSCreationDateKey) as? NSDate
    }
    var modifiedDateValue: NSDate? {
        return  NSMetadataItem(URL: self)?.valueForAttribute(NSMetadataItemFSContentChangeDateKey) as? NSDate
    }
    var nameValue: String? {
        return  NSMetadataItem(URL: self)?.valueForAttribute(NSMetadataItemFSNameKey) as? String
    }
    var displayNameValue: String? {
        return  NSMetadataItem(URL: self)?.valueForAttribute(NSMetadataItemDisplayNameKey) as? String
    }
    var fileSizeValue: Int? {
        return  (NSMetadataItem(URL: self)?.valueForAttribute(NSMetadataItemFSSizeKey) as? NSNumber)?.integerValue
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
let desktopURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DesktopDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!

print(desktopURL.creationDateValue)
```