# Find latest modified file in Folder

Tags: swift, macos

I'm trying to find the latest text file in a folder so I can open it. So far I have:

```
let logFolder = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/Library/Logs" )
let fm = FileManager.default

var files = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(at: logFolder, includingPropertiesForKeys: [.creationDateKey], options: [])
let txtFilePaths = files.filter{$0.pathExtension == "txt"}
```

But then I get stuck. I know I can get the date for a file with `txtFilePath[x].creationDate`

Seems like there should be a simple way of doing this but I'm a newbie and struggling to find any web resources for Swift 5.

Cheers

Comment: There is no simple way. Your start is basically correct. You need to enumerate all of the files and find the one with the most recent date. BTW - if you want the most recently modified file, then use the `contentModificationDateKey` key.

Answer (score 1):

Such information about files is stored in something that is usually referred to as *metadata*.

I believe you are looking for something like [NSMetadataItem](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmetadataitem#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSMetadataItem/attributes).

By following the steps presented in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35368425/11286446), you should be able to have access to a field called `kMDItemContentModificationDate`. This should help you achieve your goal.